# Создание директив в Angular 4

Tags: javascript, ооп, angular2, typescript

Недавно начал учить Angular4.
Почему при создании своих атрибутивных директив необходимо в конструкторе указывать `private` в параметрах? Например:

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
@Directive({
  selector:"[app-directive]"
})

export class MyDirective inplements OnInit{
  constructor(private eleRef:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2){
  }
  ngOnInit(){
   this.renderer.setStyle(this.eleRef.nativeElement,"color","blue");
  }
}
```

Comment: это для того чтоб депенденси инжектор ангуляра создал вам эти переменные. А слова `private` `public` нужны чтоб сразу же обьявить поля класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление операторов `private`, `public` это синтаксический сахар. Следующие два примера эквивалентны:

```
export class MyDirective inplements OnInit{
  constructor(private elemRef:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2){
  }
}

export class MyDirective inplements OnInit{
  private elemRef:ElementRef;
  private renderer:Renderer2;

  constructor(elemRef:ElementRef, renderer:Renderer2){
    this.elemRef = elemRef;
    this.renderer = renderer;
  }
}
```

В принципе такой синтаксис - это не особенность ангулара, такие возможности дает сам TypeScript, подробнее: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Предыдущий ответ не совсем полон. Так как параметры конструктора с модификатором privat ангуляр инжектирует в класс используя свой механизм инстанцирования зависимостей. Вот подробная статья на хабре - https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/281449/